# Getting a property from an object returns undefined

Tags: javascript, json, object

There is a value that I get from the app, `x`, when it is performed a JSON.stringify over it and printed it looks like this:

```
const x = JSON.stringify(someData);
console.log(`data: ${x}`);
```

result:

```
data: {"name":"myname","id":"12345"}
```

I want to get only the value of a property, for example "name", so I'm doing it like this:

```
console.log(`dataname: ${x.name}`);
```

and was expecting to see printed "myname" but instead it is `undefined`.

I don't get what's wrong.

Comment: Is the object populated asynchronously? Is `myObj` a string or an object? Please create a [mcve]

Comment: Is it JSON or an object? JSON is a *string* that *looks similar to* a literal object syntax in JavaScript. But since it's a string, it doesn't have a `name` property. If it's an object, then perhaps the values you see are populated *later* so what you see in the console is not the current representation of the object at the time of logging it.

Comment: I edited the post to be more clear

Comment: `x` is now *most definitely a string*, therefore it doesn't have a `name` property, so `x.name` will correctly produce `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure - despite there is an error in your JSON (double commas) - that it's actually an JS-Object?

First, clean this up and remove the extra ",":

```
{ 
  "name":"myname",
  "id":"ead65a6"
}
```

In your example, this actually looks like a String in JS... 
So you need to convert it into an object using `JSON.parse(myObj)`

Then you could access it like an object:

```
myObj = JSON.parse(myObj);
console.log(myObj.name);
```

Comment: If you use a ````JSON.stringify```` to (as stringify says) make a string out of the object... you first need to ````JSON.parse```` the string again to access it as an object...

Comment: doesn't work, still undefined. even if the parse() is done over the `x` or over `someData`

Comment: I don't know if there is a typo or something for you, but 
````const x = JSON.stringify({"name":"myname","id":"12345"});
console.log(`dataname: ${JSON.parse(x).name}`);````
works perfectly fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

If it's JSON, you need to convert it to object first:

```js
const obj = JSON.parse('{"name":"myname","id":"ead65a6"}');
console.log(obj.name)
```